# How to wait for clipboard action?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my Google Chrome Extension, I want to do something when the user presses CTRL+C or CTRL+X, so basically whenever they cut or copy text. Firing the event off when those keys are pressed isn't a problem, but the behavior is: copying works fine, except for the fact that it deselects the text, but cutting is even worse. It will copy the marked text, but it wont cut/remove the text and it simply deselects the text like with the copy function.

What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to wait for the cut function to finish before I work with the clipboard contents?

This is what I have, including a function that's supposed to delay the execution of the script (doesn't work, obviously):

```
function doAdelay(){
    setTimeout(function(){return true;},30000);
};

var map = {};
onkeydown = onkeyup = function(e) {
  map[e.keyCode] = e.type == 'keydown';

    if(map[17] && (map[67] || map[88])) { // CTRL + C or X
        doAdelay();

        var copiedText = window.getSelection().toString();
        var tempTextArea = document.createElement('textarea');
        tempTextArea.setAttribute('readonly', '');
        tempTextArea.style.position = 'absolute';
        tempTextArea.style.left = '-9999px';
        document.body.appendChild(tempTextArea);

        tempTextArea.value = copiedText;
        tempTextArea.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        document.body.removeChild(tempTextArea);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Your timeout function is doing nothing. The only thing you are doing is delaying the anonymous function in setTimeout() from executing. You could move your code into that function but I highly doubt adding a delay will work consistently. The keyup event is just that, keyUp. What happens after is anyone's guess. You might be able to hook into the [onCopy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/oncopy) event; probably with mixed suggest. There is also the [onCut](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/oncut) event as well.

Trying this out myself though, the copying part seems to work in Firefox. I verified this by placing a `console.log(copiedText);` after `var copiedText`. Something else is wrong with your code.

One more thing, CTRL is only used for copy-paste on Windows. On Mac, it's a different key (Command aka Windows Key aka Super Key).

Comment: Oh... my... god... I wish I knew about these functions earlier, could've saved me a lot of headaches. Thanks!